# Using closures to manually "extend" a class in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

This isn't so much a problem I'm having, rather than a general question about how classes/prototypes work in JS vs using closures. Lets say I have the following class (I'm going to omit the full body's of the methods as they are besides the point)...

```
export class SongDisplayer extends EventEmitter{
  mediaPath: string;
  currentlyPlaying: string;

  constructor(hlsMediaPath: string){
    super();
    this.mediaPath = hlsMediaPath;
    this.currentlyPlaying = '';

    this.on('currentlyPlaying', (songInfo) => {
      this.currentlyPlaying = songInfo;
    });
  };

  
  async queueDisplaySong(
    songInfo: string
  ): Promise<undefined>{
    
    const segments = await this._getM3u8Segments(this.mediaPath);

    if (!segments){
      this.emit('currentlyPlaying', songInfo);
      return;
    };

    ......
  };


  async _getM3u8Segments(
    mediaPath: string
  ): Promise<string[]>{

   ........
  };

   ......
};
```

I figure I can represent the same/similar behavior as the extends keyword by doing the following...

```
export function MakeSongDisplayer(
  mediaPath: string
){
  const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  let currentlyPlaying = '';

  eventEmitter.on('currentlyPlaying', (songInfo) => {
    currentlyPlaying = songInfo;
  });

  return {
    queueDisplaySong: (songInfo: string) => {
      queueDisplaySong(
        songInfo,
        mediaPath,
        eventEmitter
      );
    },
    on: (event: string, cb: (...args: any) => any) => {
      eventEmitter.on(event, cb);
    },
    getCurrentlyPlaying: () => currentlyPlaying
  };
};


async function queueDisplaySong(
  songInfo: string,
  mediaPath: string,
  eventEmitter: EventEmitter
): Promise<undefined>{
  
  const segments = await _getM3u8Segments(mediaPath);

  if (!segments){
    eventEmitter.emit('currentlyPlaying', songInfo);
    return;
  };

  ......
};
```

What would the potential drawbacks of doing something like the later be? My intuition is that there is probably a higher memory overhead if I where to create many of these "class" instances, because the functions in the returned "dispatch" object are duplicated on every call rather that referencing a function via the prototype chain. But I'm not clear if that's whats happening or if possibly my understanding of prototype's are fuzzy. Would love to hear any thoughts or insights!

Comment: 1/2 ... I would not worry about memory consumption (until it becomes a real issue). The decision whether to go with either of the approaches, `class ... extends` or factory function, should be made upon what's most important to the developer (team). Maintaining a real `SongDisplayer` type and working with instances of it which also feature the `EventEmitter` behavior directly or feeling more comfortable with just the glued-together object which carries the latter behavior at an own `eventEmitter` slot. I personally would choose the in my opinion _"cleaner "_ `class ... extends` approach.

Comment: 2/2 ... btw ... each instantiation via `new TypeConstructor` creates (a) closure(s) as well.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thank you for your reply! I agree, `class ... extends` is cleaner, was more just wondering about the underlying functionality. Cheers

Comment: It also depends if you use SongDisplayers that do NOT need the EventEmitter. Composing your SongDisplayer out of several classes is more flexible. You can even add the EventEmitter at runtime. Using inheritance is more rigid. I would still prefer inheritance in this case because I expect you always need the events.